# R! remove element from list which start from specific letters

Tags: list, r

I create a list of files:

```
folder_GLDAS=dir(foldery[numeryfolderow],pattern="_OBC.asc",recursive=F,full.names=T)
```

Unfortunately there is one additional object which i would like to remove (file name begin with `"NOWY" - NOWYevirainf_OBC.asc`).

How can I find index of this element on list to remove it by typing:
`folder_GLDAS<=folder_GLDAS[-to_remove]` ??

Answer (score 2):

Filter by using a regular expression.

```
folder_GLDAS <- folder_GLDAS[!grepl("^NOWY", folder_GLDAS)]
```

(You can also swap `grepl` for `str_detect` in `stringr`.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your list is one-dimensional, something like this should work:

`*folder_GLDAS<-*folder_GLDAS[substr(*folder_GLDAS,1,4)!='NOWY']`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make a (rather complex) PERL regex pattern that matches all names that end in "_OBC.asc" but DO NOT start with "NOWY": `"^(?!NOWY).*_OBC\\.asc$"`

Unfortunately the PERL syntax is not recognized by `dir`. But you could do it with `grep` like this:

```
folder_GLDAS <- dir(foldery[numeryfolderow],recursive=F,full.names=T)
folder_GLDAS <- grep(folder_GLDAS, pattern="^(?!NOWY).*_OBC\\.asc$", perl=T, value=T)
```

Also note that the "." in "_OBC.asc" needs to be escaped - otherwise you'll match for example "_OBCXasc" as well).